# Sinatra HTTP Basic Authentication get user and keep to use inside routes

Tags: sinatra, basic-authentication

I'm building an small API in sinatra. I need to authenticate the routes, and I have that already working doing the following (as read from the documentation)

```
use Rack::Auth::Basic,"Protected Area" do |username, password|
   user = User.validate username, password
end
```

But I'll have multiple users, so I'm doing something like this:

```
class Protected < Sinatra::Base
    use Rack::Auth::Basic,"Protected Area" do |username, password|
        User.validate username, password
    end

    get '/users' do
        content_type :json
        #I want to return the user who was authenticated
    end    
end
```

The class method Validate returns the user if the user does exists in the database or returns false if it doesn't exists. But what I have no idea how to do is how to access that user from inside a route, for example `get '/users' do`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If HTTP Authentication is enforced, the user's name is available in the request object, for instance:

```
use Rack::Auth::Basic,"Protected Area" do |username, password|
  User.validate username, password
end

get '/' do
  user = request.env["REMOTE_USER"]
  "Hello, #{user}"
end
```

Please note that the HTTP authentication scheme can be awkward to use, you might want to consider using [sessions](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Using%20Sessions) instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
TITLE = "Password protected Area"
# TITLE = "The page is password protected, please provide a password. (any username is ok)" # alternative title

use Rack::Auth::Basic, TITLE do |_, password|
  password != File.read("./config/password.txt").strip
end
```

is he simplest solution in my opinion.

It reads from a text file, that you should add to your gitignore